# Why the required attribute doesn't work on form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, required

I'm creating this form but when I click the button "Create Task" the required attributes are been ignored.

I'm creating the form with a innerHTML and :

```html
<form id="task-form">
  <label for="task-title">Title:</label>
  <input type="text" id="task-title" name="task-title" required>
  <label for="task-date">Due date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="task-date" name="task-date" required>
  <label for="task-description">Description:</label>
  <textarea name="task-description" id="task-description" required></textarea>
  <label for="checkbox">Add to a project?</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="task-priority">Priority:</label>
  <select name="task-priority" id="task-priority" required>
    <option value="Low">Low</option>
    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
    <option value="High">High</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" id="create-task-btn">Create Task</button>
</form>
```

Also the console give me one warning saying:
"Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Comment: Without full code, its not possible to debug the issue. This code works fine.

Comment: This message does not look like a standard javascript warning. If you're using a framwork, you should specify it in your question.

Comment: Are you creating forms dynamically? If so, provide appropriate context.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible with the code you've provided. Please provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: (Sounds like you might be trying to click the button with JS instead of letting the user do it, and not having made the HTML part of the document (i.e. have it floating in an element you created with JS that never got appended).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you are dynamically adding the form you need to create listener

```js
// Create the form element and set its properties
const form = document.createElement('form');
form.id = 'task-form';

// Create and append the form's content
form.innerHTML = `
    <label for="task-title">Title:</label>
    <input type="text" id="task-title" name="task-title" required>
    <label for="task-date">Due date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="task-date" name="task-date" required>
    <label for="task-description">Description:</label>
    <textarea name="task-description" id="task-description" required></textarea>
    <label for="checkbox">Add to a project?</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="task-priority">Priority:</label>
    <select name="task-priority" id="task-priority" required>
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" id="create-task-btn">Create Task</button>
`;

// Append the form to the document
const formContainer = document.getElementById('form-container');
formContainer.appendChild(form);

// Add an event listener for form submission
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission behavior
    // Your form submission logic here
});
```

```html
<div id="form-container"></div>
```

Comment: Forms generated by JS work as normal. They don't need a submit event listener to function.

Comment: I disagree, forms generated by JS work as normal only when using JavaScript frameworks or libraries that handle form submissions, like angular for example. check the code before you comment please !!!

Comment: Disagreement doesn’t make sense. It’s fact, not opinion. You’re simply incorrect. I’ve built forms with vanilla JS and no event listeners, they work fine.

Comment: not sure about your vanilla JS, however in this case you are wrong and thats not an opinion its a fact.

Comment: It is trivial to demonstrate that you are wrong. Delete the submit event handler from your code. The required attributes will still prevent form submission.